# Synchronizing Car Animation with Timeline Cards in HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm working on a task where I have a timeline slider and a car animation that should move below each card in the timeline. I want to synchronize the car animation with the timeline cards so that it stops below each card automatically.

I'm using Slick Slider for the timeline cards. The car animation is moving horizontally across the screen.

I've tried various approaches, but I can't seem to get the car animation to stop below each card as the timeline progresses. It either stops randomly or doesn't stop at all.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to achieve this synchronization. Is there a specific event or method in Slick Slider that I should be using? Or is there a better approach to achieve this effect?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const slider = $(".timeline-slider");
  const car = document.querySelector(".car");
  const sliderSpeed = 2000; // Adjust the slider's speed as needed
  const stopDuration = 3000; // Adjust the stop duration on each card (3 seconds in this example)
  let currentCardIndex = 0;

  slider.slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: sliderSpeed,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    speed: sliderSpeed,
  });

  // Function to move the car to the selected card
  function moveCarToCard(cardIndex) {
    // Calculate the fixed position based on the card index
    const cardPosition = cardIndex * 25; // Adjust the multiplier as needed
    car.style.left = `${cardPosition}%`;

    // Pause the car animation briefly on each card
    car.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    setTimeout(function() {
      car.style.animationPlayState = "running";
    }, stopDuration);
  }

  // Handle afterChange event to move the car when the slider changes
  slider.on("afterChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    currentCardIndex = currentSlide;
    moveCarToCard(currentCardIndex);
  });

  // Start the car animation when the page loads
  $(window).on("load", function() {
    car.style.animationPlayState = "running";

    // Set up a timer to change the slider automatically
    setInterval(function() {
      slider.slick("slickNext"); // Move to the next card
    }, sliderSpeed);
  });

  // Initialize car position
  moveCarToCard(currentCardIndex);
});
```

```css
/* CSS Styles */

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.timeline-slider {
  width: 100%;
  /* Adjust the width as needed */
  margin: 80px auto;
  /* Center the slider */
  position: relative;
}

.timeline-card {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  min-height: 271px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  margin: 0 20px;
  /* Added margin for spacing between cards */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 0% !important;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.timeline-card .year {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgba(199, 5, 5, 1);
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.road {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeRzH.png");
  animation: roadShadow 2s linear infinite;
}

.car {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 550px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: moving 10s linear infinite;
  /* Adjust the duration as needed */
}

.car img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@keyframes moving {
  0% {
    left: -2em;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  35%,
  36% {
    left: 0;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

.wheel {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: rotate 1s infinite linear;
}

.front-wheel {
  top: 40%;
  left: 18%;
}

.rear-wheel {
  top: 40%;
  left: 70%;
}


/* Define animation keyframes */

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" integrity="sha512-6lLUdeQ5uheMFbWm3CP271l14RsX1xtx+J5x2yeIDkkiBpeVTNhTqijME7GgRKKi6hCqovwCoBTlRBEC20M8Mg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<!-- Timeline Slider -->
<div class="timeline-slider">
  <div class="timeline-card">
    <div class="year">1999</div>
    <div class="details">Founded & Established</div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-card">
    <div class="year">2005</div>
    <div class="details">
      Opening of New Yard at Komaki City, Aichi Prefecture.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-card">
    <div class="year">2007</div>
    <div class="details">
      Opening of New Yard at Kisosaki Town, Mie Prefecture.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-card">
    <div class="year">2009</div>
    <div class="details">
      Opening of New Yard at Kisosaki Town, Mie Prefecture.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-card">
    <div class="year">2010</div>
    <div class="details">
      Opening of New Yard at Kisosaki Town, Mie Prefecture.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-card">
    <div class="year">2011</div>
    <div class="details">
      Opening of New Yard at Kisosaki Town, Mie Prefecture.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-card">
    <div class="year">2013</div>
    <div class="details">
      Opening of New Yard at Kisosaki Town, Mie Prefecture.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-card">
    <div class="year">2019</div>
    <div class="details">
      Opening of New Yard at Kisosaki Town, Mie Prefecture.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-card">
    <div class="year">2021</div>
    <div class="details">
      Opening of New Yard at Kisosaki Town, Mie Prefecture.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-card">
    <div class="year">2023</div>
    <div class="details">
      Opening of New Yard at Kisosaki Town, Mie Prefecture.
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Road and Car Animation -->
<div class="road">
  <div class="car">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CfNb.png" alt="Car" />
    <!-- Front wheel -->
    <div class="wheel front-wheel">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYar3.png" alt="Front Wheel" />
    </div>
    <!-- Rear wheel -->
    <div class="wheel rear-wheel">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYar3.png" alt="Rear Wheel" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery and Slick Slider scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]
[image]
[image]